# Is Ralf Hinze's Discriminator sort parallelizable?

Tags: sorting, parallel

According [to this slide](http://possiblywrong.com/presentations/generic-discriminated-sorting/#/step-5) - the following sorting algorithms

- Merge Sort
- Insertion Sort
- Bubble Sort
- Quicksort
- Bogosort

all rely on `cmp` - which has a fixed upper limit of `n log n`.

[Ralf Hinze's Discriminator sort](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/henglein2011a.pdf) is incredibly performant in linear time. According [to these tests](http://possiblywrong.com/presentations/generic-discriminated-sorting/#/step-60) in Scala it runs faster than cmp-based sorts for a linear operation.

My question is - can the [disciminator sort](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/WG2.8/31/slides/aplas2013.pdf) be parallelized?

Comment: This looks like a radix sort or trie sort. What do you know about parallelizing those?

Comment: Yes, if you do a parallel merge. The TCS question is, can you formulate Hinze's discriminator as a monoid or semigroup?

Comment: @ChadBrewbaker that would be a fascinating discussion.

Comment: Is this a general purpose sorting algorithm or does it require additional assumptions on the input (this is the case for radix sort, counting sort and bucket sort) ?

Comment: Hinze cuts GADTs off at a certain depth so you can radix/count/bucket them since you are on a fixed size domain.